# Can two bigSlide menus be placed on the one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have one bigSlide menu happily working on my page and are looking to incorporate another. The documentation does not make it clear at to whether this is possible. I've tried a few things to no avail. Has anybody had any success with having two bigSlide menus on the one page?

jQuery code used for the first menu is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-link').bigSlide({
        menu:      ('#menu'),
        push:      ('.push'),
        menuWidth: '30.6em',
        side:      'left',
        speed:     '300',
        state:      'closed',
        activeBtn:  'active',
        easyClose:  false,
    });
});
```

With the associated HTML being:

```
<nav id='menu' class='panel' role='navigation'>
    <span>
        // stuff for the menu
    </span>
</nav>
<div class='wrap'>
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-link" id='arrow' ><image src="Images/rightBlackArrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is not totally relevant. Suggest you to post WORKING [DEMO](http://www.jsfiddle.net) here.

Comment: What you are asking is altogether a new requirement which the plugin doesn't support (i guess so). So i would recommend you to write down the requirements in detail so that someone else may help you build it.

Comment: What you are asking is altogether a new requirement which the plugin doesn't support (i guess so). So i would recommend you to write down the requirements in detail so that someone else may help you build it.

Comment: After some further work it appears that I have managed to get two menus operating - so bigSlide can have multiple menus. I would like to thank the above two people for offering support in solving this issue.

Comment: Why have you not posted your solution to this issue?!

Comment: Ahhh, what a shame. I have this same dilemma and would have loved the solution posted.

Answer (score 0):

You already have all of the components in your question to make this solution work.

First, add a 2nd anchor tag as per below, and change the href and class to something unique, this lets you target these specifically when they're clicked on.

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-link" id='arrow' ><image src="Images/rightBlackArrow.png"></a>
    <a href="#menu2" class="menu-link2" id='arrow' ><image src="Images/rightBlackArrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Once done, you can then modify your script to the following; being sure to modify your class and menu as per your 2nd anchor tag above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-link').bigSlide({
        menu:      ('#menu'),
        push:      ('.push'),
        menuWidth: '30.6em',
        side:      'left',
        speed:     '300',
        state:      'closed',
        activeBtn:  'active',
        easyClose:  false,
    });

    $('.menu-link2').bigSlide({
        menu:      ('#menu2'),
        push:      ('.push'),
        menuWidth: '30.6em',
        side:      'left',
        speed:     '300',
        state:      'closed',
        activeBtn:  'active',
        easyClose:  false,
    });
});
```

EDIT: In my haste i forgot some of your form elements. Here you would create the 2nd menu alongside your first, ensuring you reference the right ID.

```
<nav id='menu' class='panel' role='navigation'>
    <span>
        // stuff for the menu
    </span>
</nav>
<nav id='menu2' class='panel' role='navigation'>
    <span>
        // stuff for the second menu
    </span>
</nav>
```